# Flaw in reasoning: number of ways to choose at least 1 man and 1 woman

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Problem: A club has 5 men and 7 women. How many ways are there to choose 4 people such that at least one man and woman are chosen?

The correct answer is 455 and can be obtained by

$${12 \choose 4} - {5 \choose 4} - {7 \choose 4}.$$

However, I am unsure of the flaw in the following reasoning below which leads to an answer of 1575:

$${5 \choose 1}{7 \choose 1}{10 \choose 2}.$$

This quantity ensures that a man and woman are chosen, and then we select two of the remaining 10 people. As a result, we have chosen 4 people, of which there are at least 1 man and 1 woman.

Comment: The former method gives $455$ when I calculate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second answer counts a slightly different problem where we not only choose a group including at least one man and one woman, but within that group, we choose a man and a woman - which gives an answer that is too high because we are making choices beyond what we were supposed to count.

Suppose, for instance, that we name the men $M_1,\ldots,M_5$ and the women $W_1,\ldots,W_7$. Your answer considers the following sequences of choices as distinct:

> We choose $M_1$ then $W_1$ and then add $M_2$ and $W_2$.
>
> We choose $M_1$ then $W_2$ and then add $M_2$ and $W_1$.
>
> We choose $M_2$ then $W_1$ and then add $M_1$ and $W_2$.
>
> We choose $M_2$ then $W_2$ and then add $M_1$ and $W_1$.

In the end, we end up with the same group from each sequence of choices - but you've counted the number of ways to make these choices *in sequence* when, in reality, several sequences can lead to the same result. Note that this can't be fixed by dividing by $4$ because, if we chose a group of one man and three women, there would only be $3$ ways to reach that group - indeed, your answer is somewhat more than $3$ times the correct answer because of this over-counting.

The suggested answer instead takes all the ways to create a group of $4$, then subtracts out those that include only a single gender - which properly counts "groups of $4$" rather than "sequences of choices".

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Suppose the men are selected from $\{\text{Adam, Bob, Carl, Dennis, Edgar}\}$ and the women from $\{\text{Alice, Barbara, Chloe, Darcy, Emily, Fiora, Gertrude}\}$.

We choose one man, say $\text{Bob}$ and one woman, say $\text{Alice}$. Then we choose two from ten that are neither of the already selected, say $\text{Emily}$ and $\text{Fiora}$.

Now for another group, choose one man, say $\text{Bob}$ once again. Then choose a woman, say $\text{Emily}.$ Now choose two out of the remaining ten, $\text{Alice} $ and $\text{Fiora}$.

Notice we've double counted the group of $\text{Alice, Bob, Emily, Fiora}$, using the latter method.